# DNS server scavenges active records

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

I have 3 DNS servers and one of them removes too many records including active ones. Last time 412 records (out of 2086 if I get it right) were removed:

```
The DNS server has completed a scavenging cycle:
Visited Zones     = 20,
Visited Nodes     = 2086,
Scavenged Nodes   = 412,
Scavenged Records = 412.

This cycle took 0 seconds. 

The next scavenging cycle is scheduled to run in 168 hours. 

The event data will contain the error code if there was an error during the scavenging cycle.
```

While two others removed 25/1135 and 5/427.
The scavenging settings are equal for all three dns servers.

Network interface settings of 2 hosts in different dns servers are equal except list of appending dns suffixes.

There is nothing relative about dhcp or dns in the host system log.

A scheduled task "ipconfig /registerdns" works as prevention.

I also tried this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2985877/cumulative-list-of-reasons-that-dns-records-disappear-from-dns-zones) (even though servers are 2012 r2) but no luck.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: How do you know the scavenged records weren't stale? Scavenging should be enabled on one server only.

Comment: I'm sure that at least some records were not stale because we lost DNS of database server in production and every time this DNS server does scavenge we lose some servers.

Comment: All three are managing different namespaces, I mentioned them just to compare amount of deleted records.